# Oracle 12c client on Windows 10 64bit

Tags: oracle, windows-10, client, 64-bit, oracle12c

I am trying to install the Oracle 12c 64bit client on a Windows 10 64bit PC.  Whenever I run the setup it just quickly pops up a DOS window then immediately closes it.  No error messages, nothing.

I know there are a few command line switches to ignore the prereq checking, but they don't appear to do anything.

Any tips are greatly appreciated...

Comment: Have you made any previous oracle installations of any kind on this particular machine?  If so, what are the names of the oracle services listed in the services control panel? (services.msc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big question is 'what do you want the client for'?  Most users can just unzip the Oracle Instant Client package(s) and not need to run an installer.  If the tools (not the OS) you use are 64-bit then install the 64-bit Instant Client from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html), otherwise if the tools are 32-bit then install the 32-bit Instant Client from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html).  Generic instructions are at the foot of each page, but check whether your tool etc has its own specific instructions.

The next question is do you really need the old 12c client?  Since 19c Oracle Client libraries (including those in Oracle Instant Client) can connect to Oracle Database 11.2 or later, you can probably install the latest-and-greatest Instant Client (or "full" Oracle Client if you really need it).

Comment: I gave up trying to find a resolution and installed the 19c client without issue.

Comment: I don't see setup.exe files in those folders

Comment: Instant Client installation is an unzip-and-set-PATH installation.  There is no setup.exe.  The download page has instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up a command prompt in the same directory as the Setup.exe file you are attempting to run, then just run the executable from the command line.  This should hopefully show what is popping up in the command prompt.

Another option to try is right clicking on the Setup.exe file and selecting **Run as Administrator**.

Answer (score 0):

Check following folders and delete them, if existing:

- %ProgramFiles%\Oracle\Inventory
- %TEMP%\deinstall*
- %TEMP%\OraInstall*
- %TEMP%\CVU*

Then open a Command Line window **as Administrator** and start setup.exe from there - perhaps you get more information.

After installation have a look at `%TEMP%\OraInstall*` there you should find a detailed log file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are running the executable from a local drive, not a removeable drive or mapped drive.
2. Make sure you have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x86 Redistributable installed.

Answer (score 0):

### Switches for Oracle Client Install procedure

setup.exe -ignoreSysPrereqs

That is to ignore higher version of Windows when install old Oracle Client.
On my experience -  Oracle 10g client installation on Windows 10

as shown
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/em.112/e12255/c_oui_appendix.htm